# Playing two videos one after another

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two video files(webm), and I want them to play one after another.

`ended` event thing is working, but when the video source changes, it's visible that one is changing to another. I don't like that.

How do I make it so that two videos (they have to be <1MB size) play as a single source?

I mean, how do I construct a blob of two videos? For example, I have video1 and video2 and I want to create such a blob, where video1 and video2 are combined and are played without visible switch from video1 to video2.

Comment: Is the second video already loaded into memory before you swap the sources? Maybe also provide us with a bit of code so we know what you have tried already

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are having is that the second video is buffering for a while after the source changes, you can put both videos on top of each other using

```
position: absolute
```

in your css for the videos. On the second video, use the [preload](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) attribute to have it load while the first video is playing. As soon as the first video is done, just hide it

```
display: none
```

and start the video that has been loading in background.

Edit1: I whipped something quick together, as a proof of concept, but you can certainly use it as a starting point and improve on it.

[Proof of concept on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjpaRW)

Edit2: Just make sure the two videos are the same size, I just took the first two could find online.

Comment: Also, you can output the video data to a canvas, which gives you a lot of options to modify it. You might have to craft custom controls, though. Here's a quick intro: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: Big thanks,man!That may be it.I'll try it out when I have some time.

Comment: You're welcome. I might try it myself at some point when I have more time. When I do, I'll post some more complete instructions.